# Product between two non-square permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning, binary-operations, permutation-matrices

Given a $n \times m$ permutation matrix $X$ (with $0 < n <= m$), I would like to show that $X'X$ must be diagonal and $XX'=I$. How can I prove that?

Note that a permutation matrix is a square (0, 1)-matrix, all of whose columns and rows each have exactly one nonzero element. Here, I am focussing on a non-square version in which each row has exactly one nonzero element (i.e., removing the condition on the columns).

Comment: There is no such matrix. If every column contains exactly one nonzero element, the matrix will have $m$ nonzero elements. Likewise, if every row contains exactly one nonzero element, the matrix will have $n$ nonzero elements in total. Yet, $m\ne n$.

Comment: I have clarified my focus further in the text. I hope it helps!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, we have an $n\times m$ matrix with $n<m$, where each row has exactly one nonzero element, but because $n<m$ each column has at most one nonzero element. Denoting by $x_{ij}$ the entries of matrix $X$, the square matrix $A=X X'$ has $a_{ii}=\sum_{k=1}^m x_{ik}^2 = 1$ on the diagonal, because each row has one $1$ and rest is $0$. Outside of the diagonal we have $a_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^mx_{ik}x_{jk}=0$, because one of $x_{ik}, x_{jk}$ has to be zero for each $k$ (if that wasn't a case, there would be a column with two or more nonzero entries).

Comment: To be explicit: I recommend not calling these matrices "permutation matrices" when they aren't square. They're perfectly good matrices to consider, but they don't permute the elements of a basis like real square permutation matrices do.

Comment: Fair enough. How about $X'X$?